# Is there any way to connect to my Oracle Autonomous Database from a website I'm creating for free?

Tags: node.js, oracle, virtual-machine

For previous websites I've made for fun, I've stored data in a google spreadsheet. But for my next personal project, I'd like to learn how to use an actual database. I'm hoping to build a website I can go to and look at a nicely-formatted set of data pulled from my database. (The next step would be using a telegram bot to add new data to the database.) I've created a free Oracle Autonomous Database and am able to access it locally through node since my IP address is whitelisted on Oracle. However, when I tried to use a google cloud function to access the database, I learned that, because of the constantly shifting IP address, this isn't possible. I also already have a google cloud VM but it too does not have a permanant IP and it looks like it costs money to reserve an external address.

So my questions are: 1) Is there an obvious simpler way to do any of this that I'm unaware of? For instance, is there a way people usually get around the IP whitelist problem when working with Oracle databases? 2) Is there a free way to serve a function with a stable IP that people recommend? and 3) for a very small personal project where I'd just be refreshing the website once or twice a day, in your experience will that end up costing so little that I should just go ahead and buy something like a static global external IP for my google VM?

Thanks in advance and let me know if there's any information I can add here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your free Oracle Autonomous Database, you can implement the functionalities you need with ORDS protected with OAUTH2.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was lost in all the different options out there and this direction is just what I needed.